# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.until

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, classpath, nosuchmethoderror

Happens error after autotests `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`:

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.until(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Environment:

- selenium-java-3
- guava-25.0-jre
- java 8
- Google Chrome 77 version
- ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40

Code:

```
WebDriverWait alertAwaiter = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 2);
alertAwaiter.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

When the second line of this code is executed,  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` occurs:

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.until(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

It is not possible to change this code, is it possible to do something using other versions of drivers or in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find a proper version of selenium library and put it to the classpath. The modern versions use `java.util.Function` instead of `com.google.common.base.Function`, see https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#until-java.util.function.Function-

So you need to you quite old version of the Selenium driver in the application classpath if you can't modify the source code.

Try to downgrade to selenium `3.0.1` or `2.x`. The latest `2.53.1` version uses guava, and version `3.0.1` seems to be the last one with guava usage.

Comment: Thank you very much! Selenium 3.0.1 and 22.0 guava solved my problem